# Extracting merged cells properties when reading an excel file into pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am reading an unstructured excel file(with lot of merged cells of no particular size) into pandas data frame and the content in merged cells is getting read into top left cell position in pandas and it fills the other cells with null values. Now there are many null values already present in the excel file and i want to find a way to specifically track the locations of cells with null values that were created after unmerging when read into pandas. I don't find any way in python that could do this thing. Could anyone guide me how to approach this problem?

Comment: This question will be difficult to answer without some "view" of the data somehow. Can you provide a text sample of the Excel file by copy and pasting into your question. Be sure to format it with the `{}` in the question editor

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use `pandas.read_excel()` to get data from Excel into the data frame?

Given the merged cells in the Excel sheet, I believe you will need to read the data yourself using one of the libraries listed on http://www.python-excel.org/ (I recommend openpyxl).

You can then control the excel-to-dataframe conversion yourself.

Comment: Thanks. ws.merged_cell_ranges does the trick using openpyxl. But I guess there is no such function in pandas??

Comment: Correct, you must write some code to create and initialize the DataFrame.